# Is there a way to upload a geotiff file directly to Earth Engine using python?

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

Is there a way to upload a particular geotiff file (from my computer) directly to the Google Earth Engine using the command line (or using a python script)?

When using the Python API, I have found just examples of moving from Google Cloud to Earth Engine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a tool called the [`Google Earth Engine Batch Asset Manager`](https://github.com/tracek/gee_asset_manager). It uses the GEE Python API as backend.

It allows you to upload single files or whole folders and automatically create image collections from them.

If you have a folder with GeoTiffs you can upload them with a single command:

`geebam upload -u <username>@gmail.com --source <path_to_directory_with_tif> --dest users/<username>/<folder>/<collection>`